# Android AlarmManager not cancelling alarms correctly

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm working on an app which will allow users to set multiple notifications, and cancel any notification they choose.

The problem I have is that when I cancel a pending intent using the AlarmManager it is cancelling all alarms. Each of my pending intents has it's own unique request code.

For instance I would call this to create the alarm and then delete:

```
setAlarm(5062, 1453269670) // Set alarm 1
setAlarm(5063, 1453774418) // Set alarm 2

cancelAlarm(5062) // Cancel alarm 1
cancelAlarm(5063) // Cancel alarm 2
```

Setting mutiple alarms always works, I can set as many as I like and they all produce the notification. However if I was to cancel alarm 1, it also cancels alarm 2.

I know that the pending intent has to be the same when setting and cancelling, and each pending intent has it's own unique request code, so I don't know why it's not working. I've spent many hours googling, but none of the suggested answers have helped me.

```
void setAlarm(int request_code, long alarm_time) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("request_code", request_code);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, request_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, pendingIntent);
}

void cancelAlarm(int request_code) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("request_code", request_code);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, request_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple

```
Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
intent.setAction("action 1");
intent.putExtra("extra", "extra1");
firstPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, firstIntent, 0);

Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
intent.setAction("action 2");
intent.putExtra("extra", "extra2");
secondPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, secondIntent, 0);
```

if you compare two PendingIntents created in ABOVE code they are NOT EQUAL

But in code BELOW:

```
Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
intent.setAction("action 1");
intent.putExtra("extra", "extra1");
firstPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, firstIntent, 0);
Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
intent.setAction("action 1");
intent.putExtra("extra", "extra2");
secondPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, secondIntent, 0);
```

if you compare two PendingIntents they gonna be EQUAL, so doesn't matter what you pass in putExtra method

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I thought the requestCode had to be unique. Setting the intent action did the job. Thanks very much.

Comment: was happy to help)